# MessageBox printing extra unicode characters from TCHAR buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

So i'm in the middle of trying to get a NamedPipe IPC project working so that my C# GUI can communicate with my C++ code, i should mention i'm a fair bit out of my depth on the C++ side at the moment, although, for the most part i have it working.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to 'translate?' the chReply buffer received by the C++ listener to a simple string and MessageBox it, i'm always getting extra unicode characters. I have added what i *think* are the most important parts.

**C# Pipe Write**

```
byte[] bReply = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("#TEST 123 456");
uint cbBytesWritten;
uint cbReplyBytes = (uint)bReply.Length;

bool bResult = PipeNative.WriteFile(hPipe, bReply, cbReplyBytes, out cbBytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
```

**C++ Pipe Read**

```
// Project's Character Set: Unicode
// BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
TCHAR chRequest[BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD cbBytesWritten, cbRequestBytes;
TCHAR chReply[BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD cbBytesRead, cbReplyBytes;
cbReplyBytes = sizeof(TCHAR) * BUFFER_SIZE;
do
{
    bResult = ReadFile(hPipe, chReply, cbReplyBytes, &cbBytesRead, NULL);
}
while(!bResult);

MessageBox(NULL, chReply, _T("GUI Request"), MB_OK);
```

If somebody could save me from drowning i would be extremely grateful.

Comment: It looks like `chReply` is not null-terminated.

Comment: Unbelievable, i just needed to null-terminate my messages with +"\0" thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VTT is right.  You need to initialize `chReply` with zeroes after each call to `ReadFile`.

Comment: s/initialize/terminate

Comment: @CodyGray initializing would work.  Terminating might be faster.

Comment: @yakk Sure, initialization would work, but it would need to be done *before* each call to `ReadFile`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems.  The first of which is that you read and discard data.  The second of which is you don't pay attention to the end of the buffer location.

```
// Project's Character Set: Unicode
// BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
TCHAR chRequest[BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD cbBytesWritten, cbRequestBytes;
std::basic_string<TCHAR> result;
do {
  TCHAR chReply[BUFFER_SIZE];
  DWORD cbBytesRead;
  bResult = ReadFile(hPipe, chReply, sizeof(chReply), &cbBytesRead, NULL);
  if (bResult)
    result.insert( result.end(), chReply, chReply+cbBytesRead/2 );
}
while(!bResult);

MessageBox(NULL, result.data(), _T("GUI Request"), MB_OK);
```

here we copy the bytes over into a `basic_string<TCHAR>`.  It automatically handles null termination and the like, and permits long messages to be passed.

We'll read them 1024 characters at a time.

Comment: I see, i'm getting an error when trying to compile that 'error C2664: '....': cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t' to 'std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t>>>' am i missing something?

Comment: @Spark heh, I typed `.back()` instead of `.end()`.  While close to synonyms in English, they are not in C++.  :)